# Change Appium time limit default value

Tags: java, appium

First of all, Hello,

Appium video recording comes as 180 seconds by default, but I want to increase this value.
For this, I made the following adjustments

```
if (testResult.getEnvironment().getOperatingSystem().equals(OperatingSystem.ANDROID)) {
    HttpEntity options = new StringEntity("{\"options\": [{\"timeLimit\": \"1800\"}]}", ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    httpPost.setEntity(options);
}
```

The video length normally being 30 minutes but still staying 3 minutes.
Can you help me, am I looking in the wrong place? Thank you.